# move view up on key board show in iOS titanium

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a text field and when I click it in android the layout moves up so the text field is immediately above the key board.

But in IOS the key board is shown over the text view.

So the user can see what he is writing.

How can I move my layout in IOS up like in android so the text field stays immediately above the key board?

I'm **not using** the **alloy folder**.

Comment: This sample code may help you :
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple : put your `TextField` into a `ScrollView` instead a `View` and the OS will handle it natively.